# SAPUI5 get OData model in controller

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

i'm making simple project in SAPUI5 and i have some problems with gettin data from OData in controller. I'm guessin if it is possible in js.

I am connected with Northwind.svc by destination.
I can easily show it in .view file using just "{/Products}", but nothing works in .controller file. 
I tried to use this.getView().getModel(), creating new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel({serviceUrl: "services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc" });

All the time i want to get propierties i'm just getting null back.

There is piece of my manifest.json file

```
"sap.app": {
    "dataSources": {
        "Northwind": {
            "uri": "/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/",
            "type": "OData",
            "settings": {
                "odataVersion": "2.0",
                "localUri": "localService/Northwind/metadata.xml"
            }
        }
    }
},

"models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "Odczyty.i18n.i18n"
            }
        },
        "": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel",
            "settings": {
                "defaultOperationMode": "Server",
                "defaultBindingMode": "Default",
                "defaultCountMode": "Request"
            },
            "dataSource": "Northwind",
            "preload": true
        }
```

neo-app.json:

```
"routes": [
{
  "path": "/resources",
  "target": {
    "type": "service",
    "name": "sapui5",
    "entryPath": "/resources"
  },
  "description": "SAPUI5 Resources"
},
{
  "path": "/test-resources",
  "target": {
    "type": "service",
    "name": "sapui5",
    "entryPath": "/test-resources"
  },
  "description": "SAPUI5 Test Resources"
},
{
  "path": "/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/",
  "target": {
    "type": "destination",
    "name": "Northwind"
  },
  "description": "Northwind OData Service"
}
```

]

Component:js

```
init: function() {
        // call the base component's init function
        UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

        // set the device model
        this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");
    }
```

models.js:

```
return {

    createDeviceModel: function() {
        var oModel = new JSONModel(Device);
        oModel.setDefaultBindingMode("OneWay");
        return oModel;
    }
};
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hello, try call this.getOwnerComponent().getModel() in your controller.

Comment: Hi, thank you for response! Already found it yesterday and it really works, but here is another problem - when i'm trying to get some properties it returning me just empty object.
I've tried with 
oModel.getProperty("/")
oModel.getProperty("/Clients(1)/Id");
oModel.getData("/");
And some other tricks but nothing returns data.

Comment: Could you please specify what object and property you want to get from NorthWind by Model?

Comment: Ahh, didn't tell u.. Yesterday i've decided to connect my friends odata in eclipse. Now the structure looks like:
https://pastebin.com/F1vDaqRH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getObject` to get your object or property from `ODataModel`, for example, you can get Email property by following:

```
oModel.getObject("/Clients(KEY)/Email")
```

Or you can get the whole object first then access the Email property

```
oModel.getObject("/Clients(KEY)").Email
```

KEY should be `9000005L` in your sample [response](http://pastebin.com/F1vDaqRH)

Comment: With the first thing ive got "undefined". Tried to use var smth = oModel.getObject("/Clients(9000005L)"); and var smth = oModel.getObject("/Clients('9000005L')");. With the second i've got "Cannot read property or undefined".

Comment: are you sure "oModel" is defined?

Comment: I think i defined, in debug mode my oMetadata has right schema with entity types

Comment: It is strange. Could you please put your whole code snippet in your question?

Comment: I'll try to work with data in java servlets, but ty for your help, maybe will be helpful for others.